# Database calls freezes 5-6 seconds every minute

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, async-await, connection-pooling

Every 60 seconds (sharp) I experience delays in a T-SQL SELECT statement inside a stored procedure and I have no clue why this happens. I suspect a misconfiguration or SQL-server bug, but I post this as a question to the community in hope that someone has solved this mystery.

I have a stored procedure called `uspLoadDocument` that loads a document when the user clicks on a document list-item. Normally, the procedure is very responsive, but every 60 seconds it "hangs" for 5-6 seconds (on average) before it continues normally (no exceptions)

Facts about this delay;

- It occurs only on my two development machines. It does not occur in production (Azure - SQL Server V12)
- It happens exactly every 60 seconds and lasts for 5-6 seconds on average
- No transactions are started (at least not in code that I control)
- Delays does not occur when SPROC is called from SQL Server Management Studio

Technical information;

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 24720 Update 1
- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64) (Express)
- Dapper 1.42.0 (No other OR/Ms in use)
- C# 6.0 and async/await pattern from WebAPI controllers all the way down to the datalayer
- Full-text search enabled and a full-text index on one of the tables inner joined in the select statement that hangs inside the stored procedure

A SQL Profiler screen-dump that shows a typical delay (long duration) on the select-statement inside the stored procedure. The left-side dump shows the anomaly that occurs every 60 seconds. The right-side shows a normal execution.

[image: SQL Profiler dumps. Delay on left side. Normal execution on right-side]

I've tried to identify the cause of these delays for almost three weeks now, and have no idea what it could be. Clues that can point in the right direction is highly appreciated

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

*Inside my stored procedure I have a select-statement that selects from a table-valued function. This function was not declared WITH SCHEMABINDING.
After adding SCHEMABINDING to the table-valued function, the delays has disappeared. Seems to me that the query-optimizer is doing some heavy processing when I don't use SCHEMABINDING.*

Comment: Wild guess maybe you have really poor data storage and slow down occurs with  [Database Checkpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189573.aspx). Anyway you should install [`sp_whoisactive`](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/) on server and monitor connections/queries because there are many possible answers.

Comment: I came across this situation when statics were not up to date and drives associated with VM ware not robust enough.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while ago.Then i came to know that the SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS was truned on in my server.It is located in
Tools->Options->SET IMPLIIT_TRANSACTIONS
Try if that  helps

Comment: Can you comment more on "the SQL-call freezes" in SQL Profiler?  E.g. which events show which durations?  If it is a SPROC or batch event, add more granular events such as SQL:StmtCompleted and SP:StmtCompleted to see where the time goes.  Perhaps add a few other events such as deadlocks, transactions, locks and database grow/shrinks, then set a filter of Duration > 1000ms.

Comment: TL;DR; You managed to pinpoint the hang to SQL Server (not your own c# code)? Can you post some code? the sql statement that hangs? I assume that you're using a LocalDB instance? or you have a express install on the same machine? perhaps on a external one?

Comment: There is still no way for anyone else to reproduce this issue, nor have you actually given us anything actionable. All we can do is guess. Run: sp_blitz, sp_blitzcache, sp_askbrent, show us the procedure, the indexes, as well as the results of those stored procedures I just listed; and then from there if you haven't already found the answer we can (most likely) help. You can find those scripts here: http://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/sql-server-downloads/

Comment: George Stocker, I'm quite confident that I have solved the problem by adding SCHEMABINDING to the table-valued function used inside the stored procedure. Could be helpful for future SO'ers if I could post it as an answer. I will post the stored procedure (is not that long/advanced) if the question is re-opened (I did not post it initially because I was quite sure the procedure wasn't the problem - my mistake)